# Как рандомно выполнить несколько команд?

Tags: javascript

На странице есть 6 блоков.

Выглядят они вот так:

[image]

При клике на какое-то число в каждом блоке идет смена числа справа.

Делаю это так:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function l_image1 (a) {
 document.numb1.src=a;
 document.numb1.value=a;
}
</script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
function l_image2 (a) {
 document.numb2.src=a;
 document.numb2.value=a;
}
</script>
```

Также есть форма со скрытыми полями:

```
  <input type="hidden" name="numb1" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="numb2" value="">
```

Суть вопроса:
Как сделать, чтобы при клике на Кнопку (Рандом, например) сначала в каждом блоке кликалось по нескольким  ссылкам (например, 5 раз) (имитировало перебор вариантов) и в конце, когда клики прекратились, заполняло соответствующие скрытое поле?

---

**ДОБАВЛЕННО:**

Сделал вот так, чтобы выбирало разные картинки:

```
<html>
<body>

<script language="JavaScript">
function randomValue(min, max) {
  var rand = (min - 1) + Math.random() * ((max + 1) - (min - 1));
  rand = Math.round(rand);
  while (rand == min - 1 || rand == max + 1) {
    var rand = (min - 1) + Math.random() * ((max + 1) - (min - 1));
    rand = Math.round(rand);
  }
  return rand;
}
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
var   arr = ["http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/0.jpg", "http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/1.jpg", "http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/2.jpg", "http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/3.jpg", "http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/4.jpg", "http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/5.jpg", "http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/6.jpg", "http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/7.jpg", "http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/8.jpg", "http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/9.jpg"];
var i1 = 0;
var i2 = 0;
var i3 = 0;
var i4 = 0;
var i5 = 0;
var i6 = 0;

z1=randomValue(5,9);
z2=randomValue(5,9);
z3=randomValue(5,9);
z4=randomValue(5,9);
z5=randomValue(5,9);
z7=randomValue(5,9);

function randImg() {

    if (i1 < z1) {
        var rand = Math.floor( Math.random() * arr.length );
        document.numb1.src=arr[rand];
        i1++;
        setTimeout(arguments.callee, 100);
    }  else{
     i1 = 0;
    }


    if (i2 < z2) {
        var rand = Math.floor( Math.random() * arr.length );
        document.numb2.src=arr[rand];
        i2++;
        setTimeout(arguments.callee, 100);
    }  else{
     i2 = 0;
    }   
    if (i3 < z3) {
        var rand = Math.floor( Math.random() * arr.length );
        document.numb3.src=arr[rand];
        i3++;
        setTimeout(arguments.callee, 100);
    }  else{
     i3 = 0;
    }   
    if (i4 < z4) {
        var rand = Math.floor( Math.random() * arr.length );
        document.numb4.src=arr[rand];
        i4++;
        setTimeout(arguments.callee, 100);
    }  else{
     i4 = 0;
    }

        if (i5 < z5) {
        var rand = Math.floor( Math.random() * arr.length );
        document.numb5.src=arr[rand];
        i5++;
        setTimeout(arguments.callee, 100);
    }  else{
     i5 = 0;
    }

        if (i6 < z6) {
        var rand = Math.floor( Math.random() * arr.length );
        document.numb6.src=arr[rand];
        i6++;
        setTimeout(arguments.callee, 100);
    }  else{
     i6 = 0;
    }
};
</script>



<table >
  <tr>
  <td><a href="javascript:l_image1 ('http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/1.jpg')" class=""><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/1.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a></td>
  <td><a href="javascript:l_image1 ('http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/2.jpg')" class=""><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/2.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a></td>
  <td><a href="javascript:l_image1 ('http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/3.jpg')" class=""><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/3.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a></td>
  <td><a href="javascript:l_image1 ('http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/4.jpg')" class=""><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/4.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a></td>
  <td><a href="javascript:l_image1 ('http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/5.jpg')" class=""><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/5.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a></td>
   <TD ROWSPAN=2> </TD>
  <TD ROWSPAN=2>
  <div id="numb1"><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/0.jpg" name="numb1" border="0" width="40" /> </div>
  </TD>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><a href="javascript:l_image1 ('http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/6.jpg')" class=""><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/6.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a></td>
  <td><a href="javascript:l_image1 ('http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/7.jpg')" class=""><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/7.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a></td>
  <td><a href="javascript:l_image1 ('http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/8.jpg')" class=""><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/8.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a></td>
  <td><a href="javascript:l_image1 ('http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/9.jpg')" class=""><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/9.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a></td>
  <td><a href="javascript:l_image1 ('http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/0.jpg')" class=""><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/0.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a></td>
  </tr>
  </table>

<br>
 <table>
  <tr>
  <td><a href="javascript:l_image2 ('http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/1.jpg')" class=""><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/1.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a></td>
  <td><a href="javascript:l_image2 ('http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/2.jpg')" class=""><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/2.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a></td>
  <td><a href="javascript:l_image2 ('http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/3.jpg')" class=""><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/3.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a></td>
  <td><a href="javascript:l_image2 ('http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/4.jpg')" class=""><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/4.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a></td>
  <td><a href="javascript:l_image2 ('http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/5.jpg')" class=""><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/5.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a></td>
   <TD ROWSPAN=2> </TD>
  <TD ROWSPAN=2>
  <div id="numb2"><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/0.jpg" name="numb2" border="0" width="40" /> </div>
  </TD>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><a href="javascript:l_image2 ('http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/6.jpg')" class=""><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/6.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a></td>
  <td><a href="javascript:l_image2 ('http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/7.jpg')" class=""><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/7.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a></td>
  <td><a href="javascript:l_image2 ('http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/8.jpg')" class=""><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/8.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a></td>
  <td><a href="javascript:l_image2 ('http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/9.jpg')" class=""><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/9.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a></td>
  <td><a href="javascript:l_image2 ('http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/0.jpg')" class=""><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/0.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  <br>

 <table>
  <tr>
  <td><a href="javascript:l_image3 ('http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/1.jpg')" class=""><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/1.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a></td>
  <td><a href="javascript:l_image3 ('http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/2.jpg')" class=""><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/2.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a></td>
  <td><a href="javascript:l_image3 ('http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/3.jpg')" class=""><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/3.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a></td>
  <td><a href="javascript:l_image3 ('http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/4.jpg')" class=""><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/4.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a></td>
  <td><a href="javascript:l_image3 ('http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/5.jpg')" class=""><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/5.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a></td>
   <TD ROWSPAN=2> </TD>
  <TD ROWSPAN=2>
  <div id="numb3"><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/0.jpg" name="numb3" border="0" width="40" /> </div>
  </TD>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><a href="javascript:l_image3 ('http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/6.jpg')" class=""><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/6.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a></td>
  <td><a href="javascript:l_image3 ('http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/7.jpg')" class=""><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/7.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a></td>
  <td><a href="javascript:l_image3 ('http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/8.jpg')" class=""><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/8.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a></td>
  <td><a href="javascript:l_image3 ('http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/9.jpg')" class=""><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/9.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a></td>
  <td><a href="javascript:l_image3 ('http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/0.jpg')" class=""><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/0.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  <br>
   <table>
  <tr>
  <td><a href="javascript:l_image4 ('http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/1.jpg')" class=""><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/1.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a></td>
  <td><a href="javascript:l_image4 ('http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/2.jpg')" class=""><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/2.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a></td>
  <td><a href="javascript:l_image4 ('http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/3.jpg')" class=""><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/3.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a></td>
  <td><a href="javascript:l_image4 ('http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/4.jpg')" class=""><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/4.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a></td>
  <td><a href="javascript:l_image4 ('http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/5.jpg')" class=""><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/5.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a></td>
   <TD ROWSPAN=2> </TD>
  <TD ROWSPAN=2>
  <div id="numb4"><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/0.jpg" name="numb4" border="0" width="40" /> </div>
  </TD>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><a href="javascript:l_image4 ('http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/6.jpg')" class=""><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/6.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a></td>
  <td><a href="javascript:l_image4 ('http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/7.jpg')" class=""><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/7.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a></td>
  <td><a href="javascript:l_image4 ('http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/8.jpg')" class=""><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/8.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a></td>
  <td><a href="javascript:l_image4 ('http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/9.jpg')" class=""><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/9.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a></td>
  <td><a href="javascript:l_image4 ('http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/0.jpg')" class=""><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/0.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  <br>
   <table>
  <tr>
  <td><a href="javascript:l_image5 ('http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/1.jpg')" class=""><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/1.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a></td>
  <td><a href="javascript:l_image5 ('http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/2.jpg')" class=""><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/2.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a></td>
  <td><a href="javascript:l_image5 ('http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/3.jpg')" class=""><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/3.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a></td>
  <td><a href="javascript:l_image5 ('http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/4.jpg')" class=""><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/4.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a></td>
  <td><a href="javascript:l_image5 ('http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/5.jpg')" class=""><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/5.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a></td>
   <TD ROWSPAN=2> </TD>
  <TD ROWSPAN=2>
  <div id="numb5"><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/0.jpg" name="numb5" border="0" width="40" /> </div>
  </TD>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><a href="javascript:l_image5 ('http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/6.jpg')" class=""><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/6.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a></td>
  <td><a href="javascript:l_image5 ('http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/7.jpg')" class=""><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/7.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a></td>
  <td><a href="javascript:l_image5 ('http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/8.jpg')" class=""><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/8.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a></td>
  <td><a href="javascript:l_image5 ('http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/9.jpg')" class=""><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/9.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a></td>
  <td><a href="javascript:l_image5 ('http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/0.jpg')" class=""><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/0.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  <br>
   <table>
  <tr>
  <td><a href="javascript:l_image6 ('http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/1.jpg')" class=""><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/1.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a></td>
  <td><a href="javascript:l_image6 ('http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/2.jpg')" class=""><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/2.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a></td>
  <td><a href="javascript:l_image6 ('http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/3.jpg')" class=""><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/3.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a></td>
  <td><a href="javascript:l_image6 ('http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/4.jpg')" class=""><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/4.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a></td>
  <td><a href="javascript:l_image6 ('http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/5.jpg')" class=""><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/5.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a></td>
   <TD ROWSPAN=2> </TD>
  <TD ROWSPAN=2>
  <div id="numb6"><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/0.jpg" name="numb6" border="0" width="40" /> </div>
  </TD>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><a href="javascript:l_image6 ('http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/6.jpg')" class=""><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/6.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a></td>
  <td><a href="javascript:l_image6 ('http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/7.jpg')" class=""><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/7.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a></td>
  <td><a href="javascript:l_image6 ('http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/8.jpg')" class=""><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/8.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a></td>
  <td><a href="javascript:l_image6 ('http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/9.jpg')" class=""><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/9.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a></td>
  <td><a href="javascript:l_image6 ('http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/r/0.jpg')" class=""><img src="http://freeloto.blogkod.ru/images/0.jpg" width="28" border="0" /></a></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  <br>

<form>
<input type="button" value="Click me" onClick="randImg();">
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

---

***Но при нажатиии на кнопку пару секунд все работает как надо, а потом браузер тупо зависает... Где ошибся?***

Comment: а вы любите копипастить, да? это жестоко.

Comment: @arashvg слишком длинный код, чтобы читать. Сделайте этот пример на [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> при нажатиии на кнопку пару секунд все работает как надо, а потом браузер тупо зависает... Где ошибся?

Лишнего накопировали: один раз запущенный `randImg()` запускает 6 таймаутов. Каждый из них, в свою очередь запустит ещё несколько себя же. Лавинообразно растёт число самовызовов.